# Downloading huggingface pre-trained models

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

Once I have downloaded a pre-trained model on a Colab Notebook, it disappears after I reset the notebook variables.
Is there a way I can download the model to use it for a second occasion?

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mount your google drive:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Do your stuff and save your models:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('/content/drive/My Drive/tokenizer/')
```

Reload it in a new session:

```py
tokenizer2 = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('/content/drive/My Drive/tokenizer/')
```

Comment: A simpler way is to use use `cache_dir` argument (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.21.0/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained.cache_dir) of a `from_pretrained` method. So, the code snippet becomes: `tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', cache_dir='/content/drive/My Drive/tokenizer/')`

Comment: That is only useful when you do not intend to modify the tokenizer (e.g. add new tokens). @Girishkumar

Comment: yes, agree. That is really a good point.  @cronoik