# Offline using cached models from huggingface pretrained

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I want to use models from:
[https://huggingface.co/ARTeLab/mbart-summarization-mlsum](https://stackoverflow.com) in offline mode, meaning that after downloading them from Hugging Face, they will be saved locally and I will be able to use them offline. However, I don't know how to do this. If anyone has already figured this out, please advise me. I use these lines to download models:

```
from transformers import MBartTokenizer, MBartForConditionalGeneration
tokenizer = MBartTokenizer.from_pretrained("ARTeLab/mbart-summarization-mlsum")
model = MBartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("ARTeLab/mbart-summarization-mlsum")
```

The problem is that when I run this line, I download several files from the repository at once, and I don’t know which one is then used for tokenization:

```
tokenizer = MBartTokenizer.from_pretrained("ARTeLab/mbart-summarization-mlsum")
```

[image]

I will be glad to receive your advice and tips!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading huggingface pre-trained models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646867/downloading-huggingface-pre-trained-models)

Just use `save_pretrained` and store it in a separate location. All files that are saved, are needed to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

HuggingFace includes a caching mechanism. Whenever you load a model, a tokenizer, or a dataset, the files are downloaded and kept in a local cache for further utilization.

You can get more information about cache management here:
https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/cache

You can use HuggingFace in offline mode:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/installation#offline-mode

> The problem is that when I run this line, I download several files
> from the repository at once, and I don’t know which one is then used
> for tokenization:

You need to download all those files to be able to load and use the tokenizer.